# Update Msql Table Using Event Scheduller with If Else Statement

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, database-trigger

How do I update a mysql table with event schedule using if...else statement. My statement is for updating age when user has a birthday. [Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL2XF.png)

```
DECLARE @user_age = DATE()
DECLARE @dateNow = DATE()
SET @user_age = t_family.bornDate
SET @dateNow = NOW()

IF (MONTH(@user_age)==MONTH(@dateNow) && DATE(@user_age)==DATE(@dateNow) THEN
   UPDATE t_family SET age = age +1
END IF
```

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Please include your code directly in the question.

Comment: There is almost nothing that is right in this code including the premise that age should be stored. I suggest you move this code to a procedure to get the code right before setting up an event  BTW a simple update statement with a where condition should do the trick.